How to setup a business Wi-Fi network but with no internet access?
I want to set up a Wi-Fi network for our company that will only allow users access to internal network resources. I do not want the users to have the ability to get on the Internet. Is this possible? I tried it on a Linksys EA7300 with no luck.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

When creating a WiFi network, the firewall zone has to be selected, so the easiest way would be to create a separate firewall zone for the WiFi network and only allowing LAN access with no WAN access. Not assigning a default gateway to the WiFi network would work, but can be easily bypassed on the client device's interface properties. OpenWrt (opensource router firmware receiving multiple updates per year) supports the EA7300 v1 and the v2, which is more feature rich and secure than the OEM firmware

Please clarify, by editing the question. whether the EA7300 is the primary router for the network (e.g. it's directly connected to a modem and receives a WAN IP on the WAN interface) or whether this is a secondary router being introduced into an already existing network that already has a primary WAN router. If the latter, the answer by @Cpt.Whale will solve the issue, whereas if the EA7300 is the primary WAN router, my previous comment would apply

Some relatively simple steps to do this with just a basic wifi router are:

Connect the wan port of your wifi router to the company network, and give it a static IP with no default gateway

Check that the route table on it now only includes one for the company network (wan interface), and one for the wifi network (lan/wlan). Both should exist automatically just by setting the IP address, and may show up in a separate "system" routing table.

With no default gateway, it loses its route to the internet, crossed out below:




If the company has multiple networks, you may have to add routes for them manually. Just specify the wan interface again, and set the Gateway for that route to the company router's IP address

Devices connected to wifi will be able to talk to the attached company network (blue), but have no way to get directly out to the internet.

If you want to give access to only specific company resources instead of the entire network, then you'll need a different kind of operating system like OpenWRT that supports detailed firewall/filtering rules.

Wouldn't simply specifying the gateway on the client device's interface properties allow bypassing this since there's no firewall rules preventing that? "If you want to give access to only specific company resources instead of the entire network, then you'll need a different kind of device that supports firewall/filtering rules." That's factually inaccurate - OpenWrt supports the EA7300 v1 and the v2, which is more feature rich and secure than the OEM firmware, with a different device not required.

@JW0914 no, you can't just specify a gateway in a different lan. If the router was bridging instead of the default of having a separate lan/wan subnets for example, then yes. You're correct about OpenWRT, I'll clarify that firewall rules require a different OS instead of entire device, thanks!

I think we may be interpreting the OP's info differently - I'm interpreting it as this is the primary router that manages the company's network, not a separate router, whereas I missed the first time this answer is regarding the router being a secondary router introduced into an already existing network with a primary router
